# Exception Breakpoints in MonoTouch

Tags: debugging, exception, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, breakpoints

I've been learning the basics of objective c/XCode with a view to using Monotouch for my actual work.  Xcode allows the idea of an '[Exception Breakpoint](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/)' and Visual Studio is similar.  Basically instead of showing the exception at the top level, it stops on the line that first resulted in an exception.

Can the same thing be done in MonoTouch ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside **MonoDevelop**, go to the **Run** menu and select the **Exceptions...** item.

That will get you an UI where you can select which exception you want to break the execution of your application.